# Understanding Bash I/O redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a pretty good idea how file descriptors work in Bash to accomplish I/O redirection in a practical level, but there is a case I found online (https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php, under "Method 2: Using Command Substitution and Redirection") that I do not fully understand why it is being used.

There is an execution that requires to redirect the stderr to stdout in order to capture the errors in a command substitution and that makes perfect sense to me, but there is an extra redirection that is done that I feel requires knowledge of how file descriptors work in a lower level. Pseudocode:

```
exec 3>&1
...
var=$(cmd -options ... 2>&1 1>&3)
...
exec 3>&-
```

What is the point of making a backup of stdout and redirect stdout to the location it was already pointing to? stdout was never altered besides now receiving the contents of stderr.

My best guess is that fd 3 contains the original state of stdout and redirecting fd 1 to fd 3 returns it to its original state before having fd 2 redirected to it? I would love some insight or reading materials.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to where you saw this? It would   be useful for context.

Comment: https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php
Under "Method 2: Use Command Substitution and Redirection"

Comment: As written, this does just sent stdout and stderr to the same fd1. But the command substitution does  a further redirection of its own -- it redirects stdout within the $(..) so it is collected and assigned to the variable (or arg). So the fd1 assigned to the command being substituted is not the same one as in the execs.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant If I understand what you are saying correctly, does that mean then that the fd1 of the command substitution is being redirected to the stdout of the parent process of the command substitution? Allowing then the stdout of the $(...) to print to terminal (in this case)?

Comment: You aren't showing the command substitution in your example, and you have skipped the discussion about "dialog needs standard output to point to the terminal so that it can display the input box" that is mentioned in the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form you wrote initially, where the command is simply `cmd -options ... 2>&1 1>&3`, this has little sense, as effectively both stderr and stdout are redirected to stdout. So `1>&3` is unneeded.

But the example you referred to is a different case. What we have there is `variable=$(cmd -options ... 2>&1 1>&3)`. The `$(command)` construct redirects stdout of `command` by itself, so that it can be captured and placed in a variable. So in this case first stderr of `command` is redirected to **already redirected** stdout (`2>&1`), ie. will be placed in the variable, and after this stdout of `command` is redirected to **original** stdout before redirection, kept in descriptor 3 (`1>&3`). The effect is that **stderr** of the `command` will be placed in the variable and **stdout** will be displayed normally - kinda opposite of "regular" `variable=$(command)` case where stdout is placed in the variable and stderr displayed. It is pretty well explained on the very same page you are linking to:

> At first glance, the redirection may seem nonsensical. First, we
> duplicate file descriptor 1 (stdout) to descriptor 3 using exec (this
> was covered in More Redirection) to create a backup copy of descriptor
> 1.
>
> The next step is to perform a command substitution and assign the
> output of a the dialog command to the variable result. The command
> includes redirections of descriptor 2 (stderr) to be the duplicate of
> descriptor 1 and lastly, descriptor 1 is restored to its original
> value by duplicating descriptor 3 which contains the backup copy. What
> might not be immediately apparent is why the last redirection is
> needed. Inside the subshell, standard output (descriptor 1) does not
> point to the controlling terminal. Rather, it is pointing to a pipe
> that will deliver its contents to the variable result. Since dialog
> needs standard output to point to the terminal so that it can display
> the input box, we have to redirect standard error to standard output
> (so that the output from dialog ends up in the result variable), then
> redirect standard output back to the controlling terminal.

Comment: I have been reading that explanation so many times and it was not clicking at all, which is why I asked the question to see if someone could explain it differently enough that it would make sense.

Comment: @AnthonyBB And has that been achieved?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It has. Your comment and Kusalananda's made me realize that I was not paying attention to the key elements that made this case work. The accepted answer supplemented what you brought up. After doing research on processes and subshells this all makes sense now. Thank you!